# Swift create instance of custom cell before loading the tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitableview

I've run into an issue. I have created a dynamic tableView with 2 prototype cells. If you could imagine say an instagram profile. It has information about you the user and the underneath has a feed of all your posts. So I recreated that UI by making a tableView with 2 cells, one is the profile part thats the first cell, then all cells after are generated from each post you have made. The problem is I do a lot of the logic of loading the user's information for the first cell in the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear of the viewController, not the custom cell class.

Therefore, the trouble I am having is sharing the outlets from the custom cell class with the view. I want to be able to access the outlets from the custom cell and give them a title, text, color, etc. before loading the table. Is there anyway to do this? How do you preload a custom cell? I wish you could make a cell non-reusable so that I can connect outlets to the viewController and avoid the "outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" error. The first cell is not repeating content its specific to the user that loads the page. So idk what to do, any suggestions? I tried making the first cell into a view(not a table cell) above the posts table with the repeating cells but then they do not scroll together as one on the page.

Answer (score 0):

> I do a lot of the logic of loading the user's information for the first cell in the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear of the viewController, not the custom cell class.

That's fine.

> I want to be able to access the outlets from the custom cell and give them a title, text, color, etc. before loading the table

But there's no need. Look, you're confusing the pieces of MVC - model, view, controller. The custom cell is *view*. All you are doing here is setting the interface, and there's no delay, no harm, no confusion in doing that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` just as for every cell.

As for getting the *information* ready beforehand, that's perfectly fine - that is *model*. You are free to do that any time, and your wish to do that way in advance is perfectly reasonable.

But handing over that model information into the view, that is *controller*, and with a table view, the moment to do that is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Don't worry, be happy. You don't have to preload anything.

Now, if the question is *how* to refer to the bits of interface in the cell when you're in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, there are lots of ways, such as tag numbers, or outlet names (using a custom cell class). But that's a minor implementation detail. Your question is *architectural*, and architecturally, what you're doing is perfectly fine.

Comment: I understand the MVC but I'm pretty sure theres a conflict that arises because I'm trying to use outlets of the populated labels and buttons in the cell within the view, when they also have to be referenced to the cell class. For instance when the view appears depending on the reference called it will either show your profile or someone elses. If it is your profile, there's a button that says "Edit your profile" if your viewing someone else's it says "Follow" or "Unfollow" in this manner this happens within the viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear, the problem is I can't access those outlets beforehand.

Comment: You don't do it beforehand. You configure it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That is where you configure the cell if it needs further configuration. And if you need to configure the view controller's view, sure, go ahead and do it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: What happens though when I have a button in the cell and it is linked to an action within the viewController that changes the title text of the button based on when you press it, how do I reference that button outlet when its outside of where the cell is initialized in the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: "when I have a button in the cell and it is linked to an action within the viewController" Then the button is the `sender` for that action, so you have a reference to it.